# Avoiding JAXBElement for substitution groups

Tags: jaxb2

I have a xsd which has the substitution groups in it . When i am trying to generate java classes using cxf wsdl2java JAXB generating List> rather than the List . How can i avoid the JAXBElement? I tried with binding.xml but its not working .Please help me to resolve this

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid the JAXBElement when using substitution groups.  The reason the JAXBElement is being created is that there is not enough information to tell which type to put into the schema because multiple types could be substituted for the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can still check for type safety at runtime using getDeclaredType. For example

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.foo");
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

File f = new File("src/Sample.xml");
SomeObject d = (SomeObject ) u.unmarshal(f);
AnyTypeContainerObject c = d.getBody();
JAXBElement<?> any = (JAXBElement<?>) c.getAny();
if ((AnyTypeObject.class.equals(any.getDeclaredType()))) {
    AnyTypeObject value = (AnyTypeObject ) any.getValue();
    ...
}
```